# Particle Swarm Optimisation "with memory"

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

Does there exist a version of [Particle Swarm Optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) "with memory", where particles avoid going to "high cost" regions (i.e. regions with high objective function value in minimisation setting)?

I guess the *memory* implementation would need to use some proxy model to represent those regions.

I'd appreciate links to papers and/or libraries that implement similar 
ideas (or other relevant sources).

Comment: Sorry if my answer is very superficial, but in a high dimensional space, if you would make steps towards a better fitness, wouldn;t the probability of returning to a bad space of the input you have already visited be very small?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's not superficial at all! The problem I'm experiencing is that the feasibility region is highly nonlinear and sparse and I'm trying to (artificially) penalize the fitness if the particle finds itself in a "wrong" (or invalid) position. So even though you're right that the particles would move towards better fitness (in general), I want them to avoid some infeasible regions (which might be close to the optimum). For this I would need some notion of memory. If this makes sense.

Comment: I see, maybe you could do something similar to firefly algorithm. Where everytime you find yourself in a bad point, all your other flireflies (e.g. individuals in your population) would go in the opposite direction of that point (i.e. if your position is x and you want to go towards x1, but avoid x2, you would go towards x+x1-x2, where you could weight each point, according to the fitness. This is similar to firefly where the brightness corresponds to the fitness and the more brightness, the more attraction towards that point).

Comment: I haven't heard of this flavour of PSO but it does not seem to solve the problem. It looks like the only difference between PSO and Firefly algorithm is the existence of absorption coefficient $\gamma$, which does not seem to be able to model complicated nonlinearities in the feasible region as fireflies do not "remember" bad positions from the past. I'd need to have some proxy function (possibly non-parametric like Gaussian Processes) that tells the "particles" to avoid some regions with very low fitness.